# Why do I have to click the language twice from the asp:listitem box to change culture?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, drop-down-menu

I have a drop-down asp:listitem box that looks perfectly clean to me.  It functions like when **the first time** you change a language on that page (Say, English to Swedish), it *does change* the text to that language.

**The second time** you try to change the language (Swedish back to English -- or any lang), it just reloads the page and then you have to select English a *second time* to actually change the page back to English.

I tried removing lines from the code behind, one at a time, but nothing changed it.  If it's possible to tell what could be the cause, any help would be truly appreciated!

My .aspx page is like this:

```
  <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCulture" DataTextField="DisplayName"
  DataValueField="Name" runat="server" BackColor="#DDE4EC" ForeColor="#465C71"
  Width="130px"  AutoPostBack="True">
  <asp:ListItem Selected="True" meta:resourcekey="MenuItemResourcelangen9">Select
  Language</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Value="en" meta:resourcekey="MenuItemResourcelangen1"></asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Value="es-MX" meta:resourcekey="MenuItemResourcelangen2">
  </asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Value="fr" meta:resourcekey="MenuItemResourcelangen3"></asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Value="de" meta:resourcekey="MenuItemResourcelangen4"></asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Value="sv" meta:resourcekey="MenuItemResourcelangen5"></asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Value="ja" meta:resourcekey="MenuItemResourcelangen6"></asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Value="nl" meta:resourcekey="MenuItemResourcelangen7"></asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Value="ru" meta:resourcekey="MenuItemResourcelangen8"></asp:ListItem>
  </asp:DropDownList>
```

My code behind is like this:

```
Partial Public Class Site
Inherits System.Web.UI.MasterPage

Private Property UICulture As String

Protected Sub InitializeCulture()
    If Session("culture") IsNot Nothing Then
        UICulture = Session("culture").ToString()
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub ddlCulture_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
Handles ddlCulture.SelectedIndexChanged
    Session("uiculture") = ddlCulture.SelectedValue
    Session("culture") = ddlCulture.SelectedValue
    Server.Transfer(Request.Path)
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Try Response.Redirect(Request.Path) instead of Server.Trasfer

Comment: That did it AVD!  Great suggestion.  I appreciate the help and the knowledge -- never thought of this until you mentioned it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

InitializeCulture is called before the Control's event (SelectedIndexChanged).

If you use Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl), the changed session settings are applied in InitializeCulture, and the page can be refreshed (F5) without a "post again?" message in the browser.

Comment: Made the change.  Works great now.  Thanks for taking the time, and teachin' me a little vb Devio!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of handling selected index changed event, I will suggest you to use `Request` object to get the selected culture in `InitializeCulture` overload. For example,

```
Protected Sub InitializeCulture()
   Dim selectedLanguage As String = Request.Form(ddlCulture.UniqueID)
   IF selectedLanguage IsNot Nothing Then
      Me.Culture = Me.UICulture = selectedLanguage
      Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = _
          CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(selectedLanguage)
      Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = New _
         CultureInfo(selectedLanguage)
   End If
   MyBase.InitializeCulture()
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the time and response, Vinay.  Both your answer and Devios made sense, and I finally got this headache to work.  Thank you for the knowledge and the time!